# A system error encountered?

Tags: 8.1, windows-10-mobile, apps, nokia-lumia-535, error

On my dual sim Lumia 535 (RM-1090, WP8.1) Whenever I open the adobe acrobat reader, it continues to display a notification of **A system error encountered ** very rapidly......almost 20-25 times per second. However no other app displays such msg nor any other problem I have to suffer. How can I cope up with this situation??? See this[image][image]

Now I have upgraded on W10M, reinstalled reader and restarted my phone several times but still my problem is intact. See the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Now what?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the app?

Comment: Yup but it did'nt work......

Comment: please try to reinstall or use any other pdf readers or time being!

Comment: Have you tried Foxit mobile PDF? It is a good alternative and is a UWP app. It would work for you.

Comment: yeah it keeps coming for me too. Try xodo docs in windows 10. Its pretty good

Comment: Since I have updated on build 10.0.14393.448 issue is resolved. Sould I answer my question with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have updated on build 10.0.14393.448 the issue is resolved. Perhaps the initial build of W10M was unable to handle with that issue but the latest build is. As it resolved the issue for that phone and in another phone updated to the mentioned version I never encountered that issue. Thanks for everyone's efforts.